# Where can I find more detailed information about Sossal?

Tags: forgotten-realms, lore

Sossal is a distant realm north-east of the Great Glacier.

[image]

It is described in just a few paragraphs in AD&D 2nd's [The Horde](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/The_Horde) and the [Grand Tour of the Realms](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Forgotten_Realms_Campaign_Setting_2nd_edition_%28revised%29) and seemingly completely ignored in the 3.5e sourcebooks.

The wiki is also very anemic, and mostly mimics what is already in those two books.

I'm not much interested in crunch, only fluff [<sup>(what?)</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-playing_game_terms) is enough.

Is there any source material on that realm (beyond what is described in the ones above)?

Comment: @sevensideddie lolz. fluff / crunch tags. good catch. Thanks as always.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the sources you've already covered, *Sossal* gets two brief mentions in the **Sword Coast Adventurers Guide**:

- On page 11 and 12, it's mentioned as part of the *Cold Lands*, along side Damara, Narfell, and Vaasa. It's said to be a small nation that trades with the rest of the Cold Lands, but that's about it.
- On page 149, its suggested as a possible origin for the *Far Traveller* background. Human natives of Sossal are described as having alabaster skin, white hair, and dressing in all white - as if they're made from the stuff of the Great Glacier.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in material in the novels and not just the sourcebooks, have a look at [*The Ruin*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/827364), the last book of The Year of Rogue Dragons trilogy by by Richard Lee Byers. Some of the events take place around Sossal and involve the Sossrim.

AD&D 2e sourcebook *Warriors and Priests of the Realms* provides information (pages 41-44) in the section "Warriors of the Cold Lands", where 4-5 paragraphs of fluff is present along with a kit for playing Sossrim warriors. The kit has a rather unusual disadvantage: once the character reaches 7th level, she/he must kill a white dragon as a rite of passage or else they cannot advance further.

For other sources, make sure you also check out the following Candlekeep discussion, which contains an extended list of Sossal-related material: http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=4445

Comment: hello, and thanks for the input. You should quote the key parts of that thread, because if that forum comes down the data is lost.

Comment: I preferred to not quote it directly before checking the validity of the information. But I got it saved on the Internet Archive's Time Machine. See here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170904222906/http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=4445